# Precompile headers in a makefile automatically

Tags: foreach, makefile, wildcard, generic-programming, precompile

Goal of my Makefile is to create in the end a static library *.a out of Fortran77 files and some *.c's + *.h's whereas a specific part of the headers have to be precompiled with a special company internal precompiler which is provided via executable and all you have to hand over is the pathname+filename.

Let's call the Precompiler CPreComp.

The files needing the precompilation *_l.h .

So I want first to collect all the headers I need to precompile and then hand it over to a script which does some magic (env variables blubb blubb) and calls the precompiler.

Here you go with my Makefile:

```
SHELL=/usr/bin/bash
.SHELLFLAGS:= -ec

SOURCE_PATH = ./src
CPRECOMP = ./tools/cprecomp.exe
DO_CPreComp = $(SOURCE_PATH)/do_cprec
HDREXT = .h
PREC_HEADERS = $(foreach d, $(SOURCE_PATH), $(wildcard $(addprefix $(d)/*, $(HDREXT))))

.PHONY: all prereq

all:: \
      prereq \
      lib.a

prereq: chmod 777 $(DO_CPreComp)
        echo $(PREC_HEADERS) >> makefileTellMeWhatYouHaveSoFar.txt

lib.a: \
     obj/file1.o \
     obj/file2.o
     ar -r lib.a $?

obj/file1.o:

# do some fortran precompiling stuff here for a specific file

obj/file2.o: $(SOURCE_PATH)/*.h precomp_path/*.h $(SOURCE_PATH)/file2.c precomp_path/%_l.h
         cc -c -g file2.c

precomp_path/%_l.h : DatabaseForPreComp.txt

precomp_path/%_l.h : 
       $(foreach i , $(PREC_HEADERS) , $(DO_CPreComp) $(i) $(CPRECOMP);)
```

So that is my Makefile, the script for the DO_CPreComp looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="(basename "$1")"
dir="$(dirname "$1")"
cprecomptool="$2"

echo ${dir} ${filename} ${cprecomptool} >> scriptTellMeWhatYouKnow.txt     

"${cprecomptool}" "precomp_path/${filename}.1" >&cprecomp.err
cp "precomp_path/${filename}.1" "precomp_path/${filename}"
```

So according to the `makefileTellMeWhatYouHaveSoFar.txt` I collect all the headers, obviously also the ones not specified with `_l.h` . This has space for improvement but the precompiler is smart enough to skip the files which are not suitable. So `makefileTellMeWhatYouHaveSoFar.txt` looks like that:

```
header1.h header2.h header2_l.h headerx_l.h headery_l.h headerz.h
```

The Error tells me:

```
path_to_here/do_cprec : line xy: $2: unbound variable
make[2]: *** [precomp_path/%_l.h] Error 1
make[1]: *** [lib.a] Error 2
```

`scriptTellMeWhatYouKnow.txt` shows me the script knows nothing and it is not even created. If I modify `cprecomptool` and directly add it in the script hardcoded the `scriptTellMeWhatYouKnow.txt` shows me the argument `$(CPRECOMP)` twice as file name and path name and the hardcoded precompiler. And ofc it ends up with Segmentation fault, so the header name was never handed over.

Additionally:
If I do not call the script in the second `foreach` but let `$(i)` be printed out with echo in another file it is empty.

Perhaps I am just too blind. And please if you are able to help me , explain it to me for dumb people, such that for the next time I stumble over a problem I am smarter because I know what I am doing. :)

Comment: You append (`>>`) to `makefileTellMeWhatYouHaveSoFar.txt`. So it is not easy to use its content to understand what just went wrong. What's in it could be there since some time. I suggest that you try to delete it first, try again to make and check its fresh content. Or directly check the content of `./src/`. Does it contain file names with unusual characters?

Comment: The last line has only an indentation of 7 - maybe some spaces instead of a TAB?

Comment: @ Renaud thanks for this comment. I delete the *.txt always before calling make. So I am for sure it's writing the correct stuff. There are only letters underscores and numbers in the file names
@ Vroomfondel Checked it 3 times, will check another time, thanks for the hint but I am hopeless.

Comment: @Denise Probably nothing to do with your problem but who knows: in your Makefile the script is named `do_cprec` but the error message shows that it is `do_CPreComp`. Is it a typo in your question or is it something else?

Comment: @Denise What happens if you add a recipe for `all` with `echo '$(foreach i , $(PREC_HEADERS) , $(DO_CPreComp) $(i) $(CPRECOMP);)'` and remove its prerequisistes?

Comment: Off topic but... the line "`prereq: chmod 777 $(CPRECOMP)`" looks rather odd.  Is that a typo?

Comment: @ Renaud Stupid typo , I had to rewrite everything because no copy&paste available, hope it is okay now. Funny thing is you are right , with the `echo '$(foreach i , $(PREC_HEADERS) , $(DO_CPreComp) $(i) $(CPRECOMP);)' ` I see it in the console. So sth is wrong with my bash-script?

Comment: @Denise Your bash script has a bogus shebang line (should be `#!`, not `!`). And you must remove the spaces around the `=` sign for `cprecomptool` assignment. So yes, it may be that.

Comment: Sorry , all what's printed out is precompiler script thre spaces precompilertool; and again ... and again... and again

Comment: @Denise Weird. Looks like `foreach` iterates over empty strings. Even if I wanted I am not sure how I could do that (with your definition of `PREC_HEADERS`). What version of make are you using?

Comment: @ Renaud
GNU Make 3.82
Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu

Comment: @Denise This is a quite old version (and I don't have it here to do some tests). What happens if you remove all spaces around commas in your `foreach` and `wildcard` calls (it is always better to avoid useless spaces with make function calls).

Comment: @ Renaud Okay I removed the spaces and I changed the `PREC_HEADERS = $(foreach d, $(SOURCE_PATH), $(wildcard $(addprefix $(d)/*, $(HDREXT))))` to `PREC_HEADERS=$(shell find $(SOURCE_PATH) -iname '*_l.h'` such that I can sort out the other headers and I was doubting wether foreach in foreach works but with this change the console shows me:

`precompile_script sourcepath/header executable etc., etc.` This looks promising. I just don't understand why two spaces are giving me such a hard time?

Comment: I also recognized just now, I accidently removed the semicolon of the `$(foreach i , $(PREC_HEADERS) , $(DO_CPreComp) $(i) $(CPRECOMP);)` while experimenting with `for i in list; do somestuff`` I will test whether this is an issue too.

Comment: @Denise My intuition is that with your version of make (not with mine) the looping variable name in your `foreach` call was "i " ("i" followed by a space, not just "i"). You can check that by restoring the original version and using "$(i )" instead of "$(i)"...

Comment: @ Renaud you are a genius, it is correct, it was the space behind the i. Thank you so much , you saved me at least an afternoon of desperate search!! Hope for your next question you are as lucky as me!

Comment: @Denise I learnt something new, on an obsolete version of make, but something new. Thanks to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, now that the main issue is solved, let's have a look at make coding styles. The make way of accomplishing what you want is not exactly using `foreach` in recipes. There are several drawbacks with this approach like, for instance, the fact that make cannot run parallel jobs, while it is extremely good at this. And on modern multi-core architectures, it can really make a difference. Or the fact that things are always redone while they are potentially up to date.

Assuming the result of the pre-compilation of `foo_l.h` file is a `foo.h` (we will look at other options later), the make way is more something like:

```
SOURCE_PATH         := ./src
CPRECOMP            := ./tools/cprecomp.exe
DO_CPreComp         := $(SOURCE_PATH)/do_cprec
HDREXT              := .h
PREC_HEADERS        := $(wildcard $(addsuffix /*_l.$(HDREXT),$(SOURCE_PATH)))
PRECOMPILED_HEADERS := $(patsubst %_l.h,%.h,$(PREC_HEADERS))

$(PRECOMPILED_HEADERS): %_l.h: %.h DatabaseForPreComp.txt
    $(DO_CPreComp) $@ $(CPRECOMP)
```

(`$@` expands as the target). This is a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern). With this coding style only the headers that need to be pre-compiled (because they are older than their prerequisites) are re-built. And if you run make in parallel mode (`make -j4` for 4 jobs in parallel) you should see a nice speed-up factor on a multi-core processor.

But what if the pre-compilation modifies the `foo_l.h` file itself? In this case you need another dummy (empty) file to keep track of when a file has been pre-compiled:

```
SOURCE_PATH         := ./src
CPRECOMP            := ./tools/cprecomp.exe
DO_CPreComp         := $(SOURCE_PATH)/do_cprec
HDREXT              := .h
PREC_HEADERS        := $(wildcard $(addsuffix /*_l.$(HDREXT),$(SOURCE_PATH)))
PREC_TAGS           := $(patsubst %,%.done,$(PREC_HEADERS))

$(PREC_TAGS): %.done: % DatabaseForPreComp.txt
    $(DO_CPreComp) $< $(CPRECOMP) && \
    touch $@
```

(`$<` expands as the first prerequisite). The trick here is that the `foo_l.h.done` empty file is a marker. Its last modification time records the last time `foo_l.h` has been pre-compiled. If `foo_l.h` or `DatabaseForPreComp.txt` has changed since, then `foo_l.h.done` is out of date and make re-builds it, that is, pre-compiles `foo_l.h` and then touch `foo_l.h.done` to update its last modification time. Of course, if you use this, you must tell make that some other targets depend on `$(PREC_TAGS)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was on a try&error trip trying to make it work and care about an optimal solutions later. This helps me improving it a lot!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Renaud Pacalet I was able to find a solution.
In the comments you can read further try & errors.

I am using GNU Make 3.82 Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu . Seems like the `foreach` does not like the space behind the i or furthermore takes the space as part of the variable.

```
# ... like beforehand check out in the question
PREC_HEADERS=$(shell find $(SOURCE_PATH) -iname '*_l.h')
# nothing changed here in between...
$(foreach i,$(PREC_HEADERS),$(DO_CPC) $i $(CPC);)
```

This has the advantage that I only precompile the headers which have the `_l.h` - ending. Having the `brackets $(i)` around the `$i` or not, doesn't make a change. What really changed everything was the space behind the first `i` .

Good luck!